# How to remove the subcolumns of a pivot table dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

## Need to drop a sub-column of multi-index data frame created from pivot table

Need to drop a sub-column only at specific columns(month) dynamically

I have a dataframe created from pivot table and need to drop a sub-column at specific columns dynamically...

**if todays date is less than 15** i need to drop the sub-column **Bill1** for all the months after **Sep-19**(**current month**)(**Bill1** to be present from jan till Sep)

**if todays date is greater than 15**, it should drop the sub-column **Bill1** for all the months after **Oct-19**(**next month**)(**Bill1** to be present from jan till Oct)

`data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)`

 `data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

`tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame1.columns]`

 `data_frame1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)`

**output:**

```
              Aug-19             Sep-19        Oct-19
             Bill1 Bill2      Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28        1    1.28      1    1.28
```

**desired Output:**

 **if todays date is less than 15**

```
               Aug-19          Sep-19        Oct-19
              Bill1  Bill2     Bill1 Bill2    Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS    1      1.28      1     1.28     1.28
```

**if todays date is greater than 15**

```
                 Aug-19         Sep-19           Oct-19
               Bill1 Bill2   Bill1  Bill2     Bill1   Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS     1      1.28    1     1.28       1     1.28
```

Comment: @jezrael..bro can u help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
         Aug-19       Sep-19       Oct-19       Nov-19      
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2
A Ind OS      1  1.28      1  1.28      1  1.28      1  1.28
```

---

```
#convert first level for datetimes and to month periods
level0 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.get_level_values(0), format='%b-%y').to_period('m')
#get second level
level1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
#print (level0)

#print (level1)

#test for next 15 days
dat = pd.to_datetime('2019-09-05')
#get today timestamp
#dat = pd.to_datetime('now')
print (dat)

#convert timestamp to period
today_per = dat.to_period('m')

#compare day and filter
if dat.day < 15:
    df = df.loc[:, (level0 <= (today_per)) | (level1 != 'Bill1')]
else:
    #test with add 1 month to today period
    df = df.loc[:, (level0 <= today_per + 1) | (level1 != 'Bill1')]
print (df)
         Aug-19       Sep-19       Oct-19 Nov-19
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill2  Bill2
A Ind OS      1  1.28      1  1.28   1.28   1.28
```

---

```
#convert first level for datetimes and to month periods
level0 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.get_level_values(0), format='%b-%y').to_period('m')
#get second level
level1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
#print (level0)

#print (level1)

#test for next 15 days
#dat = pd.to_datetime('2019-09-05')
#get today timestamp
dat = pd.to_datetime('now')
print (dat)

#convert timestamp to period
today_per = dat.to_period('m')

#compare day and filter
if dat.day < 15:
    df = df.loc[:, (level0 <= (today_per)) | (level1 != 'Bill1')]
else:
    #test with add 1 month to today period
    df = df.loc[:, (level0 <= today_per + 1) | (level1 != 'Bill1')]
print (df)
         Aug-19       Sep-19       Oct-19       Nov-19
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill2
A Ind OS      1  1.28      1  1.28      1  1.28   1.28
```

Comment: Thanks a ton bro..the symbol **|** is OR?

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - Exactly, it is bitwise `OR`, for bitwise and is use `&`

Comment: how does  #compare day and filter works?
`df = df.loc[:, (level0 <= (today_per)) | (level1 != 'Bill1')]`

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - it means get only values <= like `today_per` or values with no `Bill1`

Comment: bro how to keep the column **bill1** only in a particular month ...
can i use `data_frame = data_frame.loc[:, (level0 == 'Dec-19') | (level1 != 'Bill1')]`

Comment: Working with periods, so need `data_frame = data_frame.loc[:, (level0 == pd.Period('12-2019', freq='m')) | (level1 != 'Bill1')]`